# Is the gloss on iOS icons automatically applied?

Tags: ios, icon

Clearly it isn't completely automatic, as many icons don't have a reflection, but is there some sort of checkbox when creating an app to determine whether the gloss is applied?

Comment: I've always wondered this, since they all like identical

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is automatically applied by iOS.

There is an option for iOS application developers to turn this off, called `UIPrerenderedIcon`. This is a value in the `Applications Info.plist`, that can be turned on and off (checking it would note that this is a pre-rendered icon, and to not apply the gloss).

You can read more details in the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html).

Web Applications ([as noted in Mathias's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45830/181)) also do have this reflection applied to them. You can override this by naming your file `apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png`. [More information is also provided in the HIG for web clip icons](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW11).

Answer (score 6):

[jmlumpkin’s excellent answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45806/4408) is about native app icons. For the sake of completeness, it should be noted that there’s another type of “app” that can have home screen icons.

It’s a different story for web apps ([which can also have touch icons when added to the home screen](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons)).

A web developer can add a touch icon to his website as follows:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

iOS then automatically adds some visual effects to your icon so that it coordinates with the built-in icons on the Home screen (as it does with application icons). Specifically, iOS adds:

- Rounded corners
- Drop shadow
- Reflective shine

As of iOS 2.0, you can prevent the addition of these effects by using the `precomposed` keyword:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
```

This is described in the [Web Clip Icons section in the iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW11). There are some other gotchas [that I documented in this write-up](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons), but that’s the gist of it.